# Flutter image picker doesn't pick some images on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, plugins, imagepicker

I'm trying to pick image from gallery and it works fine. But if the image's extension is webp it's not picking it. So I can't handle the error. Cause it's not throws an error about it. Here is my code snippet:

```
try {
  final XFile? image = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery);
  if (image != null) {
    print(image.path);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

How can I handle the unsupported image format immediately? I tried timeOut but it also throws error when user viewing the gallery view and not selected image yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [File Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) instead:

> A package that allows you to use the native file explorer to pick single or multiple files, with extensions filtering support.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want.

Comment: You want to check file extension when picking up the file right?

Comment: the problem with file_picker is that, it opens iOS files App and user can't select images/videos resides in ios default photos App

Answer (score 0):

It was due to the image format (webp). After 0.8.4+10 version it fixed.